# Best way to count file downloads on a website

Tags: counter

It's surprising how difficult it is to find a simple, concise answer to this question:

1. I have a file, foo.zip, on my website
2. What can I do to find out how many people have accessed this file?
3. I could use Tomcat calls if necessary

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you could parse the log file if you don't need the data in realtime.

```
grep foo.zip /path/to/access.log | grep 200 | wc -l
```

In reply to comment:

The log file also contains bytes downloaded, but as someone else pointed out, this may not reflect the correct count if a user cancels the download on the client side.

Comment: does this tell you if the download was completed or cancelled?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way would probably be instead of linking directly to the file, link to a script which increments a counter and then forwards to the file in question.

Comment: You get download _attempts_, which is pretty reasonable.

Comment: For a bit more information the link in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16874980/1804173) is pretty useful.

Answer (score 6):

With the answer "The simplest way would probably be instead of linking directly to the file, link to a script which increments a counter and then forwards to the file in question."

This is additional:

```
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt');
$hit_count++;
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count);

header('Location: http://www.example.com/download/pics.zip'); // redirect to the real    file to be downloaded
```

Here `count.txt` is a simple plain text file, storing the counter info.
You can save it in a database table along with `downloadable_filename.ext` also.

Comment: how can i link to a script

Answer (score 0):

Use the logs--each GET request for the file is another download (unless the visitor stopped the download partway through for some reason).