# Detect user download

Tags: javascript, ieaddon

Soppose I develop a client web app (I don't have access to server code), Is it possible to detect when user downloads a file? I need something like:

```
//fires when user download file
function downloadFileCreated(obj){
    alert(obj.url); // prints the download link
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/12550657) they assume that I have access to server code (but I don't have)

(I'm working on InternetExplorer add-on and I want to inject script that listening to user download)

Comment: You want to know when the download has finished?

Comment: @Ja͢ck It will be better if I coukd know when it starts, but if ther a way to know when it end it will helpful too

Comment: What can trigger such download?

Comment: @Kaiido I'm working on InternetExplorer add-on and I want to inject script that listening to user download

Comment: That would be an important information to include in your question as an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Google analytics like mentioned in below post?

[Best way to count number of downloads of several files on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468483/best-way-to-count-number-of-downloads-of-several-files-on-website)